# Parse double char command line option in C++

Tags: parsing, c++11, command-line

I searched a lot around but found no answer:
I have to use a lot of command line options which I planed to parse with optarg (which works well for single char) - if I count all arguments the alphabet has to less letters :(
So my plan was to use double letter codes (-a, -ab, -ac ) how can I parse them ?

Would it easier to solve by using boost:programoptions?

Comment: That is horribly non-standard and a really bad idea. Far better to use long names for less used parameters or to move to a different method of passing options such as a small language, as e.g. find does. See https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html for long name parsing.

Comment: THANK YOU - I found this site already but I'm not sure if it is possible to mix both (simple and long) - I know it is not std - such things like an config file is not practicable as my tool is just a piece of a much bigger workflow therefor speed is extremely necessary

Comment: Generally the simple ones are "-a" and the longs ones are "--long". Note the two dashes. Mixing the two is common. Best practice is to offer long names for all short options, but less used ones may only have a long name version.

Comment: I see - thanks that helped - in python I would use argparse but well C++ is a different world...